# PHP - Email not sending as HTML. Why?

Tags: php, html, email, header

I am able to send plain text emails from my contact form using php, but I am not able to send the content as HTML. Thought I had added the headers correctly, but apparently there is still a problem.

This is the script I am using:

```
<?php


    $to = 'test@hotmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'From your Web';
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;


    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
        if (!trim($_REQUEST['name']) == "" ) 
        {
            if (!trim($_REQUEST['message']) == "" ) 
            {

                //send email
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
                $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
                $mail = '
                    <html>
                        <body>
                             <table border=1>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name:</td>
                                <td>'.$name.' </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email:</td>
                                <td>'.$email.'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Msg:</td>
                                <td>'.$message.'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </body>
                        </html>
                ';

                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                mail($to, $subject, $mail, "From:" . $email, $headers);
                //mail($to, $subject, "From: " . $name . "/" . $email . " Msg: ".$message, "From:" . $email);
                echo 'Thank you!';

            }
            else{

                echo 'No empty msg';

            }   
        }
        else{

            echo 'This is not a name';
        }
    }
    else{

        echo 'No correct email';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what does it do exactly...?

Comment: [php site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) lists the format as... `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` but it seems like... you have too many things.  they include the `from` in their headers section... so... does that code error?  or not?  seems like it should error... with too many arguments for the mail function.  but idk.

Comment: ohhh it wouldn't error... b/c there's option params, too.  no error.  yeah.  so follow the format and your code should work.  take out the `"From:" . $email,` part completely.  test it.  then add the `from` in your headers following the format on the documentation page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.  code is un-tested.  and it's been eons since i've written in php so i could have easily mangled some syntax in there.

```
$tacos   = "crunchy";

$to      = "tacos4eva@email.com"; 
$subject = "tacos"; 
$mail    = "the tacos are $tacos today."; 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: taco_master@email.com' . "\r\n";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $mail, $headers); 

if ($success) echo "tacos were sent successfully"; 
         else echo "tacos fell on the floor";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

from the page...

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be
>   set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in
>   php.ini.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, to send email as HTML, you have to use the proper headers, otherwise best case, you'll just end up with a mangled email.

Comment: arguably... to do anything, you must use proper code or you'll probably get distorted results.  or errors.  usually errors.