# how to send email as html template using php webmail

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to send email using PHP script I am successed. Instead of plain text I want to send an HTML template which contain CSS design and tabled data but I am getting plain text. Here is the code:

```
$headers='Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"';
                      $from = 'UCVOGUE';
                      $subject = 'Order Confirmation from UCVOGUE';
                      $message = '<html>
                      <body>
                      <div class="col-md-12 email-box">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <img src="images/clogo.png" width="50%" class="center-block">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <center><h2>Greetings from Ucvogue</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <center><h3>Order No:12501468</h3></center>
            </div>
          </div><hr>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Custome:name</td>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>Cost</td>
                    <td>Units</td>
                    <td>Total Cost</td>
                    <td>Address:</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $o_cu_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $o_pro_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $o_pro_cost;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $o_qty;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $o_cost;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $o_cu_address;?></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          </body>
          </html>
          ';
                      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

see the screenshot attached how i am getting plain text instead of bootstrap html template model

Comment: your bootstrap might not follow along and you need to add styles by yourself. Create a `template.html` and in your php file use `$message = file_get_contents(template.html)`. try if this works

Comment: I think you need a MIME and/or FROM header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884043/php-email-not-sending-as-html-why?rq=1

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp check example 3

Answer (score 0):

try to use this $headers variable :

```
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
```

and then  change the mail function to

```
mail($to,$subject,$message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php/#example-3960)

(used iso-8859-1 as It is the basis for most popular 8-bit character sets)